# Get ActiveX checkbox status (checked or not checked)

Tags: vba, excel

How do you access the value of a checkbox' status. I was expecting to see something like a Value property which would be True if the checkbox is checked. However, the following does not work:

```
Worksheets("Summary").Shapes("chkbxRunLocally").controlform.Value
```

It throws:

```
Object does not support this property or method
```

If this is not where the property stored, where then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're not using an `ActiveX` checkbox, this one *has* a `.value` but if you access it directly as an object variable, i.e.

```
 Debug.Print Worksheets("Summary").chkbxRunLocally.Value
```

If you are using a normal Excel shape (non ActiveX), Try this:

```
Debug.Print Worksheets("Summary").Shapes("chkbxRunLocally").ControlFormat.Value = 1
```

or also

```
Debug.Print Worksheets("Summary").CheckBoxes("chkbxRunLocally").Value = 1
```

Notice the `=1` which is True if the shape is checked, False if unchecked. When it is unchecked, the returned `.Value` is `-4146` which is also true if converted directly to a Boolean. The test `=1` decides (as Boolean) whether the control is actually checked or not.

Comment: the first line worked with my activeX checkbox. Thanks!